# How often is php updated?

Tags: php

I am using ubuntu 10.04.  I had installed php with the following command if that makes a difference:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

The PHP version on my computer is 5.3.2-1. Will PHP be upgraded any further on this version?  If so, where can I find out when the next upgrade will be released and what version it will be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would point you to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-php-5-4-0/109544#109544 where is the answer which will allow you to upgrade to PHP5 from my PPA which carry the latest available PHP packages.

Comment: You find the PHP versions released with each Ubuntu release here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/338842/how-to-know-what-version-of-php-is-shipped-in-a-release-version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After Ubuntu is released, it is considered stable. That means having as few changes as possible. Only necessary changes are added. Such updates are called Stable Release Updates (often called SRUs). You can read more about that process here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates

Answer (score 5):

Programs aren't generally updated in Ubuntu unless they absolutely have to. The current version of the program at release time is what goes in the repositories. After that, only critical security updates are allowed. So, you'll either have to upgrade Ubuntu or manually download the current version of PHP.