# How to know what version of PHP is shipped in a release version?

Tags: php, versions, release-management

Is there a page or Wiki listing for each Ubuntu release what is the default associated PHP version?

```
10.04 LTS => PHP 5.3.2
```

And so on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com) website. [It's pretty handy for this stuff](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php5&searchon=names&exact=1&section=all).

Here is the current output:

```
lucid (php): server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
5.3.2-1ubuntu4.20 [security]: all

lucid-updates (php): server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
5.3.2-1ubuntu4.20: all

precise (php): server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
5.3.10-1ubuntu3.7 [security]: all

precise-updates (php): server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
5.3.10-1ubuntu3.7: all

quantal (php): server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
5.4.6-1ubuntu1.3 [security]: all

quantal-updates (php): server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
5.4.6-1ubuntu1.3: all

raring (php): server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
5.4.9-4ubuntu2.2 [security]: all

raring-updates (php): server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
5.4.9-4ubuntu2.2: all

saucy (php): server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
5.5.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1: all
```

As of Xenial Xerus the keywords string to search is "php". (the version is PHP7)

```
xenial (php): server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (default)
1:7.0+35ubuntu6: all
also provided by: php7.0

xenial-updates: Virtual package
provided by: php7.0

yakkety (php): server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (default)
1:7.0+42: all
also provided by: php7.0
```

Answer (score 3):

This page lists the different versions of `php5` in different release of Ubuntu:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) was the first Ubuntu release to ship with PHP 7 instead. So the link changes to:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php7.0

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I understand that this is generally what we want on askubuntu.com, but if you consider the actual question, I don't think this policy applies here.

Comment: In fact, rather the opposite. Since the page I linked to is autogenerated and part of the Ubuntu publishing infrastructure, including the essential parts of the content will cause this answer to become invalid, not the linked page.

Comment: I would have linked [this one instead](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+publishinghistory) and provide an excerpt or how-to use instead. Because, he could go to the link but don't understand what he's seeing.

Comment: @RobieBasak I agree. But I recommend expanding this answer a bit, even if only to include a slight rewording of what you said in [that comment](http://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/152616#comment432111_338867) about why the page you've linked to is a good resource. That way, people who view this in the future will understand that it is likely to still apply. If you wish, you might also consider providing some of the information [Braiam suggested](http://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/152616#comment432115_338867).